# How to fix error 1064 while trying to add foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am trying to set up a DataBase for a library and after I created the table and trying to create foreign keys I get this error (1064) and I relly dont know what to do. I am using MySQL 8

I searched and I couldnt find anything similar. All I found was problem with reserved words , something I dont think is the problem in this case.

```
ALTER TABLE `project`.`book` 
ADD INDEX `pubName_fk_idx` (`pubName` ASC) VISIBLE;
;
ALTER TABLE `project`.`book` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `pubName_fk`
  FOREIGN KEY (`pubName`)
  REFERENCES `project`.`publisher` (`pubName`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Error message:

> Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to
>   the database. Executing:

```
ALTER TABLE `project`.`book` 
ADD INDEX `pubName_fk_idx` (`pubName` ASC) VISIBLE;
;
ALTER TABLE `project`.`book` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `pubName_fk`
  FOREIGN KEY (`pubName`)
  REFERENCES `project`.`publisher` (`pubName`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

> ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2
>   SQL Statement:

```
ALTER TABLE `project`.`book` 
ADD INDEX `pubName_fk_idx` (`pubName` ASC) VISIBLE
```

Comment: Been a while since I played with MySQL, but could it be that wayward extra `;`?

Comment: No I already tried , the only thing I found working was removing the INDEX code line but I dont think  its the right thing to do.

Comment: CREATE INDEX instead of ADD INDEX perhaps?

Comment: No, still the same error

Comment: What version of mysql are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MariaDB or MySQL under 8.0, they have not inplemented the VISIBLE or INVISIBLE index, so you need to change your query:

```
ALTER TABLE `project`.`book` 
ADD INDEX `pubName_fk_idx` (`pubName` ASC)
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much you kind sir! Have a nice day!